# Jenkins Set User API Token from file instead of generating in UI

Tags: jenkins, hash, token, reverse-engineering

Is there a way to set the API token of a user manually? In the UI it has a button "Change API Token" which generates the token. Instead I want to set it.

Our old jenkins server crashed and we have to create a new one. Lot of teams are using a remote trigger call similar to below one. Change in the API token impacts all these teams as they have to update their code.

```
curl -X POST -H "$CRUMB" "http://automation:ef*****************************d@jenkins-url.com/job/log_deployment/buildWithParameters?token=B6472A215********************
```

The API token in UI is 32 char long. Upon checking the file in jenkins/users//config.xml there is this property jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty. Seems like it is possible to set this, need some direction please.

```
<jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
  <apiToken>{AQAAABAAAAAwOROgeIy1vAUUOtGIYud+70TXY0pS/pKTe7nLeO8Xtd2BDgXW1RlZ6pL9+bvDrbwHh2xBnebPJAUS3OQt8f/toQ==}</apiToken>
</jenkins.security.ApiTokenProperty>
```

Thanks!

Update: More info from
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-32776

> User
>   passwords are stored as salted hashes (SHA-256 or bcrypt); whereas API tokens
>   are encrypted using an AES-128 ECB-mode block cipher, using a static key shared
>   among all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a given token explicitly since Jenkins only stores the hash of a token.

You can, however, copy the hashed value, thus effectively *copying* a token.

To do this between different masters with different global encryption keys, you need to decrypt the hash of the first master and use that for setting the hash on the second master. It's probably easiest to do that in groovy.